# Create a flavour with openstack SDK

Tags: python, openstack, openstacksdk

I have a heat template yaml file for creating a flavor named **"flavor_one"** on compute node placed at specific path /opt/config/template.yml

How can I create a flavor with the template file with openstack SDK in python.
I tried with the below. But failed:

```
 image = conn.create_flavor(
                    filename='/opt/config/template.yml' + flavor_one,
                    wait=True)
```

Any help ? I am a novice at openstack SDK. I have successfully established a connection with clouds.yaml file

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but as far as I can see, `create_flavor` [takes a single argument](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/proxies/compute.html#flavor-operations), namely a dictionary of flavor properties. I also believe that you need to call it as `conn.compute.create_flavor`.

Comment: I can't find any property for passing `template` file from its [source code](https://github.com/openstack/openstacksdk/blob/master/openstack/compute/v2/flavor.py#L38), so it might be unsupported now.

Comment: Check this : openstack.compute.v2.flavor https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/resources/compute/v2/flavor.html#openstack.compute.v2.flavor.Flavor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the create_flavor method...

```py
import json, openstack

try:    
  os_connect = openstack.connect(
       auth_url="https://controller:5000/v3/",
       project_name="admin", username="admin",
       password="secretPassword",
       region_name="RegionOne",
       user_domain_name="Default",
       project_domain_name="default",
       app_version='1.0')

  # Change name, ram, vcpus, disk to your favourite values
  os_connect.create_flavor(name, ram, vcpus, disk, flavorid='auto', ephemeral=0, swap=0, rxtx_factor=1.0, is_public=True)
```